# filter_var($url, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED) always returning false

Tags: php, url, php-7, filter-var

filter_var($url, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED)  is always returning false. Below is my code, I can't figure out why it is false on all urls.

```
$url = $this->input('website'); //form input

if ( $parts = parse_url($url) ) {
    if ( !isset($parts["scheme"]) )
        {
            $url = "https://$url";
        }
}

if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED)) {
    dd('not valid  '.$url);
}
else {
    dd('valid  '.$url);
}
```

if I enter 'www.cnn.com' in the form, the following is the result:

```
not valid https://www.cnn.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to `filter_var` must be one of the [primary filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php); `FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED` is not a filter, it's an *option flag* for the `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` filter. So:

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 2):

`FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED` is an option of `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` and can't be used on its own.

You should do:

```
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    dd('not valid  '.$url);
}
else {
   dd('valid  '.$url);
}
```

Beware that `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` uses [RFC2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html) which is outdated.

If you want better URL validation use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) which uses [RFC3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html) which obsoletes RFC2396 and better handles more modern edge cases.